# Efficiency of horizontal scaling when Multiple Deployment of same container on a single Host

Tags: docker, containers, horizontal-scaling

Do we get efficiency in terms of load handling when the same container (in this case the container has a apache server and a php application) is deployed 5 or more times (i.e. 5 or more containers are deployed) on the same Host or VM?

Here efficiency would mean whether the application in such an architecture is able to serve more requests or serve requests faster?

As far as i am aware, each request launches a new apache-php thread and if we have 5 containers handling the requests then will it be inefficient since now the threads launched by apache will be contextually be switched out more often?

Answer (score 2):

Scaling an application requires understanding why the application has reached it's limit. For this, you need to gather metrics from the application and host when it is fully loaded. Without testing and gathering metrics, you're only guessing why you've at capacity.

If the application is fully utilizing one or more cpu cores, but not all of them, then it is either not multi threaded, or is encountering locks preventing all the cores from being used. Adding more containers to the host in this scenario may help scale.

Typically, horizontal scaling is done because a single host is using all of some resource, like disk io, network bandwidth, memory, or cpu. If you find that the app is using all of one or more of these resources when under heavy load, then you need more hosts, not more containers running on the same host.

This all assumes you haven't configured docker to limit resources on the containers. If you reach your capacity with one container, and have resource limits configured, then the easiest way to get further performance is to remove or reduce those limits.